# Lasso does not converge

Tags: regression, python, lasso, regularization, linear

I have a 2000x100 matrix (100 features, 2000 observations). I am trying to do a simple lasso regression (L1 regularization). However, the algorithm does not converge (I use lasso of sckit_learn in python2.7).

I have normalized the data (using normalize=True).

What could be the cause? I suspect colinearity can be an issue, but is there anything else I should explore to understand why it does not converge?